tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority" node="master-node"
I am trying to create multi master with single load balancer in k8s.
The load balancer is nginx with ssl, I am using cert boat to create certificate and it is showing all the certificate is there in it.
while trying to initialize the init command in the k8s server with --control-plane-endpoint as nginx server domain.
$ sudo kubeadm init --control-plane-endpoint=my.domain.com:443 --upload-certs --apiserver-advertise-address=172.31.40.245 --pod-network-cidr 10.244.0.0/16.
iam getting this error
"Apr 18 07:26:58 master-node kubelet[34761]: E0418 07:26:58.656108 34761 kubelet_node_status.go:96] "Unable to register node with API server" err="Post "https://my.domain.com:443/api/v1/nodes%5C": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority" node="master-node"".
version.
Client Version: v1.29.2
Kustomize Version: v5.0.4-0.20230601165947-6ce0bf390ce3
nginx version: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu).
Tried adding the certificates to k8s folder "/etc/kubernetes/pki/"
issue is same.
I am attaching the nginx.conf also.
upstream backend_servers {
    server <master1 ip>:6443;
    server <master2 ip>:6443;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name my.domain.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.domain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.domain.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    location / {
        # Use the load balancer for proxying requests to backend servers
        proxy_pass https://backend_servers;

        # Proxy settings
        proxy_redirect          off;
        proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}

Please help me to fix this.
tried to add crt to /opt/Kubernetes/pki/ folder.
updated certs in /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
update-ca-certificates.
tried to change the data in cert from CA:FALSE to true. To change the value in trust list it was other-entry tried changing it to authority
